# why won't Tee write all output being given (Bash)?

Tags: bash, function, logging, tee

I've run into a problem which I don't know the cause of. I guess the easiest way to explain is by a code example:

```
test ()
{
    echo "This will be printed to the file"

    #But the output of rsync will not
    rsync -av /path/A /path/B

    echo "This will be printed to the file"
}

function_calling_test ()
{
    test | tee -a "file_B.txt"
}

function_calling_test | tee -a "file_A.txt"
```

In the above example **file_A.txt** will contain both **echo** output and the **rsync** output from the function **"test"**, but **file_B.txt** will only contain the **echo** output. Why is this?

Comment: For what is worth, I get the same output in both `file_B.txt` and `file_A.txt`. The only thing that isn't on any of the files is what `rsync` prints to `stderr` because isn't being redirected.

Comment: Be very careful about a function called `test`; there's a built-in command called `test` too, more commonly used as `[` but both exist.  Or maybe, under `bash`, the `test` command is the one from `/bin`, but still be cautious about using `test` for your own purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the stderr output to the stream

```
mytest ()
{
    echo "This will be printed to the file"

    #But the output of rsync will not
    rsync -av /path/A /path/B 2>&1
    # -----------------------^^^^^^

    echo "This will be printed to the file"
}
```

`test` is a command available to all unix shells that is part of the unix/Linux OS. Don't name your functions just plain test, you're setting yourself up for an accident! ;-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: "Test" was just an example, I don't actually have a function named that :) But I don't get the output even though there's no error output, it seems strange... But I'll will try your suggestion later tonight. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you, I found that the error was somewhere else while I was manipulating the file which tee was writing to. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Good job debugging your problem! Thanks for the votes. Continued success! ;-)